# Calculate Max from set of Calculated Measure in powerPivot

Tags: max, powerpivot, dax

I have created a model in PowerPivot, and have many calculated measure to get the share value (%). 
EX:

```
 1. Brand 1   15%
 2. Brand 2   34%
 3. Brand 3   51%
```

To get each brand Share value i have written a Dax formula as below:

```
 =(Sum(Column A)/Sum(Column b)).
```

Now i need to get the max of the share value (%) from the list of Brands we have. Can someone help me write another formula to get the max of share Value among all the brands.
i.e. Brand 3 51%.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your model I can only propose to try measure below (if measure for brand shares is called ValueShare).

```
MaxShare = MAXX(ALL('Product'[Brands]),[ValueShare])
```

[image]